# Update multiple state with same value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to update multiple state when I check the box mean the useSameInfo is true.

For example if fieldName is `assignFirstName` then I want to update `billFirstName` with this value also.

```
updateValue = (fieldName, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.useSameInfo) {
      if (fieldName === 'assignFirstName') {
        // update billFirstName state also
      } else if (fieldName === 'assignLastName') {
        // update billLastName state also
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      [fieldName]: event.target.value,
    });
    console.log(this.state);
};
```

What should I write in the line commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object and populate it accordingly before calling the `setState`

```js
updateValue = (fieldName, event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const updates = {
    [fieldName]: event.target.value
  };
  if (this.state.useSameInfo) {
    if (fieldName === 'assignFirstName') {
      updates.billFirstName = event.target.value;
    } else if (fieldName === 'assignLastName') {
      updates.billLastName = event.target.value;
    }
  }
  this.setState(updates);
  console.log(this.state);
};
```

Comment: It says: `[ts] Property 'billFirstName' does not exist on type '{ [x: number]: any; }'.` I am using TypeScript not JavaScript.

Comment: @Khuong In that case i believe you could write it like `updates['billFirstName'] = event.target.value`